# Why does url_for() gives routing.BuildError error in Flask html template

Tags: python, html, flask

When I start my flask app I get this error:

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'index'. Did you mean 'home_view.index' instead?
```

I have this basic html template. `index.html`:

```
<br/>
<center>
    <h1>Welcome to my Web Page</h1>


</center>

<br/><br/>

<a href="{{ url_for('about') }}"> About me</a>
```

And I also have this `home_view.py` file which renders that page:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

home_bp = Blueprint("home_view", __name__)


@home_bp.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

In all the sources I see, they reference the functions responsible for these views directly. Why am I getting this error where it requests the filename before the function?

Comment: Can you share the file that starts the flask app?

Comment: @ilias-sp I start it in a bit convoluted way I can share it but maybe I can answer your question what do you want to see?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38566481/flask-blueprint-url-for-builderror-when-using-add-url-rule

Comment: That is how flask works. If the route is in a blueprint then url_for takes `blueprint_name.method_name`

Comment: imo this is not the same question. KZiovas asked why is it happening and not how to fix it